# Selecting one row based on the values in a group

Tags: sql, group-by, subquery

Novice SQL coder here. My data looks like this:

```
Case          Allegation          Result
1             1                   Supported
1             2                   Not Supported
2             1                   Not Supported
3             1                   Not Supported
3             2                   Supported
3             3                   Not Supported
4             1                   Not Supported
4             2                   Supported
```

For my purposes, a case is considered "supported" if any allegations within it are supported. What I need to do is to return one row per unique Case which reads "Supported" if that condition is met, and otherwise reads "Not Supported":

```
Case          Result
1             Supported
2             Not Supported
3             Supported
4             Supported
```

In the past I'd have "over-selected" what I needed and done the display work through Reporting Services expressions, but this time I'm delivering a query. I'd imagine I need a subselect with groups for this but haven't the first idea of how to do it.

Comment: Have you [**tried anything so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)? :)

Comment: hint. use group by case and return max(result)

Comment: simply use `SELECT DISTINCT Case FROM AllegationsTable WHERE Result='Supported'`

Comment: @ibo you can return Not Supported if there is no Supported

Comment: @maSTAShuFu I don't get it, how can it return not supported if there is a WHERE Result='Supported'?

Comment: @Ibo OP - For my purposes, a case is considered "supported" if any allegations within it are supported. What I need to do is to return one row per unique Case which reads "Supported" if that condition is met, and otherwise reads "Not Supported":

Comment: oh, then you need to run a left join with the table itself, just make sure you use distinct again

Comment: @Ibo shall you check my solution. cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.[case], 
            CASE 
              WHEN c.result IS NULL THEN 'Not Supported' 
              ELSE 'Supported' 
            END AS result 
FROM   t AS a 
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT b.[case], 
                     b.result 
              FROM   t AS b 
              WHERE  b.result = 'Supported') AS c 
          ON a.[case] = c.[case];
```

**Result:**

```
case    result
1   Supported
2   Not Supported
3   Supported
4   Supported
```

You can see it here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9c217/47

Comment: Thank you, I thought it might be something simple. I really did just need to select distinct, then condition the allegation table join on the allegations being supported, then select with a case statement marking all cases without supported status as not supported.

Comment: I am not sure if you had an ID column in your tables, but it is a very good practice to have it in all of your tables. It would have been a lot easier to get the same results if you had

Comment: @DStein don't forget to always choose the correct answer or upvote people (answers or comments). That is how members get credits for their efforts

Comment: @lbo Definitely, I don't think my votes are counted yet but I've upvoted everybody I learned from. Hoping to get to the point knowledge-wise where I can pay it forward as well.

Comment: @DStein I cannot see any votes. There is a checkmark next to the answers and you should choose one as the right answer and you can upvote it too. The cast is visible instantly

Comment: Apologies -- got it. The other solutions were really great and thoughtful though I checked yours for the reasons I noted above.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
Select 
   t.[case], 
   case when existSupported.case is not null then “Supported” else “Not Supported”
 From table1 t
    Left join (select distinct [case] from table1 where result = ‘Supported’) existsSupported 
  on t.case = existsSupported.case
```

Should get you there

Comment: how did you get there?

Answer (score 0):

GROUP by the CASE field 
Max of the Result field (where S is higher than N)

```
declare @mytable table ([case] smallint, allegation smallint,result varchar(20))

insert into @mytable
values (1            , 1                 ,'Supported'),
(1           ,  2                   ,'Not Supported'),
(2          ,   1                   ,'Not Supported'),
(3        ,     1                   ,'Not Supported'),
(3       ,      2                   ,'Supported'),
(3      ,       3                   ,'Not Supported'),
(4     ,        1                   ,'Not Supported'),
(4     ,        2                   ,'Supported')



select [case], max(result) [Result]
 from @mytable
group by [case]
```

Result

```
1   Supported
2   Not Supported
3   Supported
4   Supported
```

Comment: it is really a nice shortcut but if at some point result changes to be a different value or data type or a foreign ket then your method will fail and cannot even be modified to get the same result

Comment: don't even know if this is a shortcut as i am just solving the OP in the simplest form based on the requirements. you cannot really assume other values since they are all ready given in the OP.